# Can I get Performance Monitor to stop a Data Collector Set when a process exits?

Tags: windows-7, performance-monitor, perfmon

I am currently debugging a program crash and need data on its memory usage over time. This crash often happens after an extended amount of time open, especially overnight.

To this end, I have defined a Performance Monitor Data Collector Set to log the process' memory usage. However, due to the long running-time, I do not want to leave the counters active indefinitely. And due to the unknown end-time I am unable to use any of the duration stop conditions:

[image: Data Collector Set properties -- Stop Condition]

How can I stop the collection when the process ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there doesn't seem to be an option within Performance Monitor itself, the command-line interface (`logman`) opens the possibility for a scripted solution.

PowerShell has the command `Wait-Process`, which blocks until the specified process ends.

Combining those, we get the solution, in PowerShell:

```
Wait-Process programname; sleep 30; logman stop datacollectorsetname
```

The sleep is there to allow time for the collector to log one or two entries after the process ends.